# Criar uma modal em instancia, e depóis destrui-la

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, json

Possuo em meu sistema muitas partes onde o usuário da um duplo clique em determinada linha, e é carregado a ação correspondente dentro de uma modal Bootstrap.

No método atual que eu utilizo, existem três elementos modal indicando:

```
#primary-layer-modal

#secondary-layer-modal

#third-layer-modal
```

Esses três elementos ja são carregados vazios com a interface, e ficam esperando a serem chamados e preenchidos.

O que eu quero fazer é de algum modo 'instanciar' um elemento (na hora que uma solicitação ajax for feita) que possa ser invocado na instância, e ser destruído posteriormente, pois no modo atual, essas modais são resíduos desnecessários.

O que eu pensei como solução:

Deixar apenas uma `div` na `index` com identificação:

```
<div id="residual-elements"></div>
```

E solicitar a renderização de um modal ao meu framework e devolver junto com o json da resposta:

```
$modal = new \vidbModel\modalElements();
$elemento = $modal->background('static')->footer('close|submitFakeForm')->title('Titulo da modal')->body($html)->modal(0);
echo json_encode($elemento);
```

E utilizar de:

```
$('#residual-elements').append($respostaAjax);
```

Pra inserir a modal na página.

E usar de:

```
$('#residual-elements').empty();
```

Pra destruir a modal após sua utilização.

Bom, isso não está me parecendo a melhor forma de fazer isso pois em certos casos eu teria uma resposta json muito grande trazida do servidor.

Eu não tenho muita prática com JS, e acho que seja com ele eu vá ter uma solução melhor.

A dúvida é:

> Como seria a lógica pra eu ter um 'criador de elementos' instanciado client side que eu não precise solicitar ao PHP o elemento em questão?

Ou,

> Qual seria uma possível forma de instanciar um elemento que poderá ser
>   reaproveitado constantemente client side ?

OBS:
1 - Meu JS é bem fraco.

2 - O ambiente que estou tentando realizar isso é para diminuir o consumo do servidor em transitar com grandes respostas nas solicitações.

Comment: Está resposta em Json é grande quanto? vc não pode colocar um "carregando" enquanto vc "monta" o modal?

Comment: Grande seria uma estrutura de elementos inteira, todos os elementos da modal, mais o conteúdo que pode ser desde um formulário com um input, até uma tabela com +300 linhas que vão solicitar outras modais secundárias que podem conter mais elementos que solicitam mais uma camada de modal.
Atualmente tem um 'carregando', ele carrega rápido sem problemas, o problema é que são necessárias muitas requisições. Eu quero ganhar desempenho nisso e outras coisinhas pois tenho problemas de desempenho em partes mais complicadas de solucionar.

Comment: eu tenho algo parecido aqui, o que faço e manter o máximo de coisas fixas no modal... e em vez de reescrever tudo... mudo apenas as partes que necessito alterar, para isso uso div com id para ir preenchendo com por exemplo: $('#id).html(conteudo);